# How can I find the average dead-end length and escape length of a self avoiding walk?

Tags: java, arrays, conditional-statements, simulation, random-walk

I'm building a program that takes command-line arguments n and trials and computes trials self-avoiding walks in an n-by-n lattice. For each walk, it creates a boolean array, starts the walk in the center, and continues until either a dead end or a boundary is reached. The result of the computation is the percentage of dead ends. Increasing the number of experiments increases the precision.

I have been able to simulate the self-avoiding walk and calculate the average length of the walk, but I am trying to find the average dead-end length and escape length of the simulation. I have tried to find the dead-end length by first using this statement within the dead-end if statement:

```
deadEndLength += length;
```

After the if statement:

```
System.out.println("Average dead-end length" + deadEndLength/deadEnds);
```

This statement results in a length that is incorrect and too large.  Now, I am trying to make deadEndLength an array that is currently present in the code below.

I have also tried implementing Math.abs() for the x and y values to calculate the length, but it doesn't seem to help me find a solution.

n: lattice size

trials: number of trials

deadEnds: number of trials resulting in a dead-end

escapes: number of trials resulting in an escape

length: length of all trials in terms of distance

deadEndLength: length of trial resulting in a dead-end

escapeLength: length of trial resulting in an escape

a[][]: intersections visited

x, y: current position

r: random number in (0, 1)

```
public class SelfAvoidingWalkMod 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int trials = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        int deadEnds = 0;
        int escapes = 0;
        int length = 0;
        int escapeLength = 0; 
        double[] deadEndLengths = new double[trials];
        for (int t = 0; t < trials; t++)
        {   // Do trials random self-avoiding walks in an n-by-n lattice.
            boolean[][] a = new boolean[n][n];
            int x = n/2;
            int y = n/2;
            while (x > 0 && x < n - 1 && y > 0 && y < n - 1)
            {   // Check for dead end and make a random move.
                a[x][y] = true;
                if (a[x-1][y] && a[x+1][y] && a[x][y-1] && a[x][y+1])
                {
                    deadEnds++;
                    for (int i = deadEnds; i < deadEnds+1; i++)
                    {
                        deadEndLengths[i] = length;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                double r = Math.random();
                if      (r < 0.25) { if (!a[x+1][y]) x++; length++; } // If the value of random is less than 0.25, then if the coordinate at a[x+1][y] is false, add 1 to the x coordinate and add one to length
                else if (r < 0.50) { if (!a[x-1][y]) x--; length++; }
                else if (r < 0.75) { if (!a[x][y+1]) y++; length++; }
                else if (r < 1.00) { if (!a[x][y-1]) y--; length++; }
            }
        }
        escapes = trials - deadEnds;
        System.out.println(100 * deadEnds/trials + "% dead ends");
        System.out.println("Dead-ends: " + deadEnds);
        System.out.println("Length: " + length);
        System.out.println("Average length: " + length/trials);
        System.out.println("Average dead-end length: ");
        System.out.println("Average escape length: ");
    }    
}
```

EDIT:

```
    for (int t = 0; t < trials; t++)
    {   // Do trials random self-avoiding walks in an n-by-n lattice.
        boolean[][] a = new boolean[n][n];
        int x = n/2;
        int y = n/2;
        length = 0;
        while (x > 0 && x < n - 1 && y > 0 && y < n - 1)
        {   // Check for dead end and make a random move.
            a[x][y] = true;
            if (a[x-1][y] && a[x+1][y] && a[x][y-1] && a[x][y+1])
            {
                deadEnds++;
                deadEndLength += length;
                break;
            }
            double r = Math.random();
            if      (r < 0.25) { if (!a[x+1][y]) x++; length++; } // If the value of random is less than 0.25, then if the coordinate at a[x+1][y] is false, add 1 to the x coordinate and add one to length
            else if (r < 0.50) { if (!a[x-1][y]) x--; length++; }
            else if (r < 0.75) { if (!a[x][y+1]) y++; length++; }
            else if (r < 1.00) { if (!a[x][y-1]) y--; length++; }
        }
        totalLength += length;
    }
    escapes = trials - deadEnds;
    escapeLength = totalLength - deadEndLength;
    System.out.println(100 * deadEnds/trials + "% dead ends");
    System.out.println("Dead-ends: " + deadEnds);
    System.out.println("Total length: " + totalLength);
    System.out.println("Average length: " + totalLength/trials);
    System.out.println("Total dead-end length: " + deadEndLength);
    System.out.println("Average dead-end length: " + deadEndLength/deadEnds);
    System.out.println("Total escape length: " + escapeLength);
    System.out.println("Average escape length: " + escapeLength/escapes);
}
```

}

Comment: Shouldn't you be dividing the deadEndLength by deadEnds, not by trials?

Comment: Also, length isn't reset after each trial, so it is the total length, not the length for that trial.

Comment: Thanks. For the former, yes. For the latter, I'm not sure how to restructure the loops to make a counter for the length of deadEnds and the length of escapes.

Comment: You could have another variable for the totalLength, and reset the length to 0 on each trial. (And add up totalLength += length; at the end of each trial.)

Comment: I have just added my revision to the original post using totalLength and it prints reasonable code. Thank you!

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, and try to isolate the problem.

Comment: Are you sure your conditional logic `if (r < 0.25) { if (!a[x+1][y]) x++; length++; } ` and the lines that follow is correct? The way it is now length will be incremented even if x or y is unchanged.

Comment: You're absolutely right. My syntax was improper.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I'm still learning. I will use those articles as a reference going forward.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).